# CSS isn't working can anyone debug my code?

Tags: html, css

Oke so heres my problem: I've got a parent  `div` with one `h2` and one `p` and when i remove the wrapping `div` from the `h2` and `p` my css works normally, but as soon as i add the `div` again my `Top:;` element stops working for the `p`

Heres my code:

```css
#p3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  max-width: 39%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2 id="identities">Identities</h2>
  <p id="p3">One may identify as non-binary on its own or they may identify as a gender that falls in the category of non-binary.<br><br> Any gender that is not strictly and completely male or strictly and completely female falls under the category of non-binary.<br><br>    Some common non-binary identities include:
  </p>
</div>
```

This is what it does without the `div` parent:

[image: Stuff showing normally]

and this is what happens when i add the `div` parent:

[image: Stuff changing]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve] when asking a question

Comment: Why is the paragraph set to position relative?

Comment: Can you add a drawing (use gimp, paint, whatever) of what you expect.

Comment: please add your full css (or your div and h2 at least), so the issue can be replicated .. and solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to target the `p3` element better. Try this code out

css

```
div > #p3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  max-width: 39%;
}
```

html

```
<div>
  <h2 id="identities">Identities</h2>
  <p id="p3">One may identify as non-binary on its own or they may identify as a gender that falls in the category of non-binary.<br><br> Any gender that is not strictly and completely male or strictly and completely female falls under the category of non-binary.<br><br>    Some common non-binary identities include:
  </p>
</div>
```